# Get screen size on iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, xcode6

I tried `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` to get the screen size of a resizable iPhone on `Xcode 6` simulator. But it doesn't  take into account the new screen width and screen height I assign to it.

Is there a better way to get the screen size? Even if I set the screen size to **320x800** the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` returns me `(CGRect) $0 = origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=768, height=1024)`

[image]

Comment: In a view controller have you tried self.view.bounds?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do following

**CGRect Rect=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];**

So it will preserves the bounds in the rect.
try once.

Comment: You need to remove the * for this to work. It throws an error otherwise.

Comment: This is not working using iOS 8.4.1 on iPhone 5. Is detecting the screen size of iPhone 4/4S

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4.0, 3.0

```
let screenRect:CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

This gets in iOS8 and iOS9. Not sure about 7 haven't tested:

```
var screenWidth: CGFloat {
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(screenOrientation) {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    } else {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    }
}
var screenHeight: CGFloat {
    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(screenOrientation) {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
    } else {
        return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    }
}
var screenOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
}
```

These are included as a standard function in:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions